# How do we set up the subscriber key in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I am new to Marketing cloud and recently started working on it.I have Service cloud org where i have my contact data.Now i want to connect my service cloud with marketing cloud Org.For this i Used Salesforce MC Connect.I completed this trailhead for Salesfoce MC Connect.https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-connect
But Somehow now i am not able to send the email from Service Cloud org.i am getting the queue error.
I have following question now.

1. Do we need to set up the subscriber key before using MC
   connect.because its mentioned in one of help document.  if Yes,How
   do we set up the subscriber key. I have searched enough but i didnt
   get how to setup suscribe key.
2. what is import model from Service Cloud to Marketing Cloud

   - How do we filter the contacts we are importing?
   - How do we import data from custom/standard objects
3. How do we set up the data extensions properly?

Comment: Please select as accepted answer if I have answered your question.

Comment: Please read my comment still it doesnt answer properly.

Comment: All the resources you would need are located in the answer. You will need to put in some effort yourself.

Answer (score 3):

1. If you want Individual Email Results passed back to Service Cloud then use ContactId or LeadId as your subscriber key.
2. Your objects can be synchronized in Contact Builder > Data Sources. These show up in the Synchronized Data Extensions folder. They can be queried using a query activity.
3. Data extensions can be sendable or relational data extensions. This is a loaded questioned depending on how you need your data set up.

Resources:

IER: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214356&type=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Synchronized DEs: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_implement_synchronized_data_sources_best_practices.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Data extensions: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_salesforce_data_extensions.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Comment: Firstly i want to know how to setup subscriber Key.is it required if we want to send email form sales/service cloud..

Comment: If you are using Marketing Cloud and Marketing Cloud Connect with Sales/Service Cloud, you'll need a subscriber Key: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_subscriber_key.htm&type=5.

Comment: But how subscriber Key is setup?any idea..